# Receiving bool values as a response to http request

Tags: rest, http, go

I have two services communicating with each other using http requests and responses. One specific endpoint in Repo-1 returns a bool value as it's response.

```golang
response := checkIfPresent(personId)
return c.JSON(http.StatusOK, response)
```

Here `response` is a bool value. And on the client side, I am receiving the response like this.

```
client := &http.Client{}
responseBody, err := client.Do(request)
if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    
defer responseBody.Body.Close()

response, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(responseBody.Body)

return response
```

However, here response is of the type `[]byte`. How do I get the bool value from this and return it?

Comment: why not unmarshal response? https://play.golang.org/p/IoWV0UXXcD0

Comment: `bytes.Equal(bodyBytes, []byte("true"))` ? : / >.<

Comment: Also, reuse the `http.Client`; don't create a fresh one for each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `response` is a JSON encoded data in a byte slice, containing the string `true`. You have to unmarshal it from the JSON.

```
var resp bool
err := json.Unmarshal(response, &resp)
if err != nil {
  //Do the error handling, and return, for example:
  return false, err
}
return resp, nil
```

Or simply you can check if its equal to the string "true" with

```
return string(response) == "true"
```

But later if the response will contain more data, only the unmarshal way will be valid.